# library not found for -lBranch after React Native 0.62 Update

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, branch.io

This started happening on a few libraries after the 0.62 and 0.62.1 updates for React Native. Thanks in advance!

```
Ld Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/******.app/****** normal x86_64
    cd /Applications/******/ios
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target x86_64-apple-ios8.0-simulator -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.4.sdk -L/Applications/******/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L<Multiple -Lvalues> -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -F/Applications/******/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/******/ios/Frameworks -F/Users/brotsky/Documents/FacebookSDK -F/Applications/******/ios/GoogleSdk -F/Applications/******/ios/Pods/Crashlytics/iOS -F/Applications/******/ios/Pods/Fabric/iOS -F/Applications/******/ios/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Applications/******/ios/Pods/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks -F/Applications/******/ios/Pods/Intercom/Intercom -F/Applications/******/ios/Pods/OneSignal/iOS_SDK/OneSignalSDK/Framework -F/Applications/******/ios/Frameworks -filelist /Applications/******/ios/Build/Intermediates.noindex/******.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/******.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/******.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Applications/******/ios/Build/Intermediates.noindex/******.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/******.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/******_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lBranch -lCocoaAsyncSocket -lDoubleConversion -lFBReactNativeSpec -lFBSDKCoreKit -lFBSDKLoginKit -lFBSDKShareKit -lFirebaseCore -lFirebaseCoreDiagnostics -lFirebaseInstanceID -lFlipper -lFlipper-DoubleConversion -lFlipper-Folly -lFlipper-Glog -lFlipper-PeerTalk -lFlipper-RSocket -lFlipperKit -lFolly -lGoogleDataTransport -lGoogleDataTransportCCTSupport -lGoogleUtilities -lPermission-Camera -lPermission-Contacts -lPermission-FaceID -lPermission-LocationWhenInUse -lPermission-MediaLibrary -lPermission-Microphone -lPermission-Notifications -lPermission-PhotoLibrary -lRCTPagedContacts -lRCTTypeSafety -lRNCAsyncStorage -lRNCPushNotificationIOS -lRNDateTimePicker -lRNDeviceInfo -lRNFBAnalytics -lRNFBApp -lRNFBCrashlytics -lRNFastImage -lRNGestureHandler -lRNPermissions -lRNReanimated -lRNSVG -lRNScreens -lRNSentry -lRNShare -lRNVectorIcons -lReact-ART -lReact-Core -lReact-CoreModules -lReact-RCTAnimation -lReact-RCTBlob -lReact-RCTImage -lReact-RCTLinking -lReact-RCTNetwork -lReact-RCTSettings -lReact-RCTText -lReact-RCTVibration -lReact-cxxreact -lReact-jsi -lReact-jsiexecutor -lReact-jsinspector -lReactCommon -lReactNativeDarkMode -lSDWebImage -lSDWebImageWebPCoder -lSentry -lYoga -lYogaKit -lc++ -lcrypto -levent -levent_core -levent_extra -levent_pthreads -lglog -licucore -llibwebp -lnanopb -lreact-native-branch -lreact-native-camera -lreact-native-config -lreact-native-contacts -lreact-native-document-picker -lreact-native-fbsdk -lreact-native-geolocation -lreact-native-image-picker -lreact-native-intercom -lreact-native-netinfo -lreact-native-network-info -lreact-native-onesignal -lreact-native-splash-screen -lreact-native-webview -lsqlite3 -lssl -lstdc++ -lxml2 -lz -framework Accelerate -framework AdSupport -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreTelephony -framework Crashlytics -framework FIRAnalyticsConnector -framework Fabric -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework Foundation -framework GoogleAppMeasurement -framework ImageIO -framework Intercom -framework JavaScriptCore -framework MobileCoreServices -framework OneSignal -framework Photos -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework UserNotifications -framework WebKit -framework iAd -weak_framework Accounts -weak_framework AudioToolbox -weak_framework CoreGraphics -weak_framework CoreLocation -weak_framework Foundation -weak_framework QuartzCore -weak_framework Security -weak_framework Social -weak_framework UIKit -ObjC -lc++ -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Applications/******/ios/Build/Intermediates.noindex/******.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/******.build/******.app-Simulated.xcent /Applications/******/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-network-info/libreact-native-network-info.a /Applications/******/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Branch/libBranch.a /Applications/******/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-onesignal/libreact-native-onesignal.a /Applications/******/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-config/libreact-native-config.a /Applications/******/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNVectorIcons/libRNVectorIcons.a /Applications/*****/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNPermissions/libRNPermissions.a /Applications/*****/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-ART/libReact-ART.a /Applications/*****/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeDarkMode/libReactNativeDarkMode.a /Applications/*****/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-intercom/libreact-native-intercom.a -framework CoreFoundation /Applications/*****t/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKCoreKit/libFBSDKCoreKit.a -framework CloudKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework SafariServices -framework AddressBook -framework CoreData -lsqlite3.0 -lz -lPods-****-***** -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Applications/******/ios/Build/Intermediates.noindex/****.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/****.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/*****_dependency_info.dat -o /Applications/******/ios/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/*****.app/****

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L<Multiple'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-Lvalues>'
ld: library not found for -lBranch
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by adding `$(PROJECT_DIR)/Pods/Branch` to my `Framework Search Paths`.